# Smali byte format- what does the "t" mean?

Tags: smali

I'm working on understanding some smali code and I'm trying to understand a variable declaration. The code is:

```
.field protected static final VARIABLE_NAME:B = 0x16t
```

I understand the variable must be a byte, but what does the "t" mean afterwards?

Thanks!

Comment: See if this page is helpful, https://code.google.com/p/smali/wiki/TypesMethodsAndFields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

t is the suffix for a byte literal.

```
t - byte
s - short
l - long
f - float
d - double
```